# Append several variables to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I want to append several variables to a list. The number of variables varies. All variables start with "volume". I was thinking maybe a wildcard or something would do it. But I couldn't find anything like this. Any ideas how to solve this? Note in this example it is three variables, but it could also be five or six or anything.

```
volumeA = 100
volumeB = 20
volumeC = 10

vol = []

vol.append(volume*)
```

Comment: It might help if you could give an example that's closer to your situation. I.e., how did you end up with a variable number of variables whose names aren't known?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `extend` to append any iterable to a list:

```
vol.extend((volumeA, volumeB, volumeC))
```

Depending on the prefix of your variable names has a bad code smell to me, but you can do it. (The order in which values are appended is undefined.)

```
vol.extend(value for name, value in locals().items() if name.startswith('volume'))
```

If order is important (IMHO, still smells wrong):

```
vol.extend(value for name, value in sorted(locals().items(), key=lambda item: item[0]) if name.startswith('volume'))
```

Comment: what if I already have some elements in list?                                                                                                                                                I tried it and get a error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 7):

Although you can do

```
vol = []
vol += [val for name, val in globals().items() if name.startswith('volume')]
# replace globals() with locals() if this is in a function
```

a much better approach would be to use a dictionary instead of similarly-named variables:

```
volume = {
    'A': 100,
    'B': 20,
    'C': 10
}

vol = []
vol += volume.values()
```

Note that in the latter case the order of items is unspecified, that is you can get `[100,10,20]` or `[10,20,100]`. To add items in an order of keys, use:

```
vol += [volume[key] for key in sorted(volume)]
```

Comment: +1; if you have a bunch of variables whose names are in some sort of sequence, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: The variables result from other calculations (which i did not post here). If I would use a dictionary I had the problem to first put them into a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** removed `filter` from list comprehension as it was highlighted that it was an appalling idea.

I've changed it so it's not too similar too all the other answers.

```
volumeA = 100
volumeB = 20
volumeC = 10

lst =  map(lambda x : x[1], filter(lambda x : x[0].startswith('volume'), globals().items()))
print lst
```

Output

```
[100, 10, 20]
```

Comment: your comment makes me realise how wrong I was :D - Smile tomorrow is Valentine's day.

Comment: It's even uglier to switch to using `map` just to continue to use `filter`. I think JBernardo's point was that comprehensions already have an optional if clause built-in, so use that instead of `filter`.

Comment: The eve of valentines day, I thought love was meant to be in the air, obviously not blind love. :/ You're right of course and I got JBernardo's point but instead having a 'me-too' answer I thought I'd go for consistency in my lack of attractiveness.

Answer (score 2):

do you want to add the variables' names as well as their values?

```
output=[]

output.append([(k,v) for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith('volume')])
```

or just the values:

```
output.append([v for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith('volume')])
```

Answer (score 1):

if I get the question appropriately, you are trying to append different values in different variables into a list. Let's see the example below.
Assuming :

```
email = 'example@gmail.com'
pwd='Mypwd'

list = []

list.append(email)
list.append (pwd)

for row in list:
      print(row)

 # the output is :
 #example@gmail.com
 #Mypwd
```

Hope this helps, thank you.