# adding a variable to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I am a bit confused about how I can add a variable to a list in python.  I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860460/append-several-variables-to-a-list-in-python)

and this was not very helpful.
This is the code I have:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
        something = 4
        print(lst.append(something))
```

This for some reason returns none.  Unsure if I am missing something.  Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Well, that's totally understandable because `list.append()` always return `None` and you are actually trying to print what this `append()` function is returning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does list.append() return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016802/why-does-list-append-return-none)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods: clear / extend / reverse / append / sort / remove) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-clear-extend-reverse-append-sort)

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
something = 4
res = [int(something)]
print(lst + res)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
something = 4
lst.append(something)
print(lst)
```

Comment: This answer returns none.

Comment: Does it now? I ran this on a debugger